# UI Issues - adding uialeartview, tabbaritems and tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

1. ) I have seen some applications like `Foursquare` and `Twitter`, where they ask to hold the tableview down to reload/refresh the table. How can i add this feature to my application ?

2.) I need to add a textbox in a `UIAleartView`, and i know this is not permitted. So what are Libraries available to get this done ? (Only the libraries apple approves)

3.) In `foursqure`, i have seen the checkin tab bar item's height is greater than the other tab bar items. I need to increase the tab bar item when the user selects it. How can i do this ? any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second question answer is goes here,

In this the Reference link you can shows the add subview into UIAlertviewControll and their is replace by your textbox thus your problem may be solve by this

[Refer the Reference link for question two here](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/21/uitableview-in-uialertview-with-sbtablealert-ios-open-source/)

**Update Code and put into method**

```
-(IBAction)btnSave
{

    UIAlertView *saveAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter a name for your count" message:@"     " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save",nil];
    UITextField *txtSave = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 45, 245, 25)];

    [txtSave becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"txtSave became first responder");
//  [saveAlert setTag:UIAlertViewID_Save];
//  [txtSave setTag:UITextFieldID_txtSave];
    [txtSave setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtSave setPlaceholder:@"Enter name here"];
    [txtSave setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    [txtSave setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [txtSave setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [txtSave setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [txtSave addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];  
    [saveAlert addSubview:txtSave];
    [saveAlert show];
//  [txtSave release];
//  [saveAlert release];
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Log");
}
```

It may be help to solve your problems.
In your third question answer goes here in which the in tabbar you can create the you customize tabbar with use of the your single image put into them and you can easily manage the tabbar so that Refer the below link for the customize tabbar.

[Refer the Reference link for question third here](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/01/customizing-tab-bar/)

Comment: And your first question is recent search on that and give the proper answer on that.

Comment: You got some great tutorials (Y). Will Apple allow us to add additional fields to the UIAlertView ? 3rd Question - I want the tab bar to look like the one shown in the foursquare App (http://venturebeat.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/foursquare-checkin.png) <--- Look at the Check-In Tab

Answer (score 2):

For #1 you can look at open source code EGOTableViewPullRefresh. Download it from here:

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/blob/master/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/Classes/View/EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m

For #2, check out **textFieldAtIndex:** method for UIAlertView Class. Seems you have to use one of the following styles:

```
UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput
UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
```

So clearly it is permitted. Not sure where you got your info from.

For #3 you cannot adjust the height. I think it is a readonly property. Apple has designed specific UI elements from a UX perspective and dont allow changes to them as they think it violates HCI principles.

But ofcourse you can hide the tabbar, create your own custom uiview and do practically anything you want.